# Spark - Java UDF returning multiple columns

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

I'm using sparkSql 1.6.2 (Java API) and I have to process the following DataFrame that has a list of value in 2 columns:

```
ID  AttributeName AttributeValue
 0  [an1,an2,an3] [av1,av2,av3]
 1  [bn1,bn2]     [bv1,bv2]
```

The desired table is:

```
ID  AttributeName AttributeValue
 0  an1           av1
 0  an2           av2
 0  an3           av3
 1  bn1           bv1
 1  bn2           bv2
```

I think I have to use a combination of the explode function and a custom UDF function.

I found the following resources:

- [Explode (transpose?) multiple columns in Spark SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220916/explode-transpose-multiple-columns-in-spark-sql-table)
- [How do I call a UDF on a Spark DataFrame using JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348058/how-do-i-call-a-udf-on-a-spark-dataframe-using-java)

and I can successfully run an example that read the two columns and return the concatenation of the first two strings in a column

```
 UDF2 combineUDF = new UDF2<Seq<String>, Seq<String>, String>() {
        public String call(final Seq<String> col1, final Seq<String> col2) throws Exception {
            return col1.apply(0) + col2.apply(0);
        }
    };

 context.udf().register("combineUDF", combineUDF, DataTypes.StringType);
```

the problem is to write the signature of a UDF returning two columns (in Java).
As far as I understand I must define a new StructType as the one shown below and set that as return type, but so far I didn't manage to have the final code working

```
StructType retSchema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
            new StructField("@AttName", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("@AttValue", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
        }
    );
```

context.udf().register("combineUDF", combineUDF, retSchema);

Any help will be really appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I'm trying to implement first the zip(AttributeName,AttributeValue) so then I will need just to apply the standard explode function in sparkSql:

```
ID  AttName_AttValue
 0  [[an1,av1],[an1,av2],[an3,av3]]
 1  [[bn1,bv1],[bn2,bv2]]
```

I built the following UDF:

```
UDF2 combineColumns = new UDF2<Seq<String>, Seq<String>, List<List<String>>>() {
        public List<List<String>> call(final Seq<String> col1, final Seq<String> col2) throws Exception {
            List<List<String>> zipped = new LinkedList<>();

            for (int i = 0, listSize = col1.size(); i < listSize; i++) {
                List<String> subRow = Arrays.asList(col1.apply(i), col2.apply(i));
                zipped.add(subRow);
            }

            return zipped;
        }

    };
```

But when I run the code

```
myDF.select(callUDF("combineColumns", col("AttributeName"), col("AttributeValue"))).show(10);
```

I got the following error message:

*scala.MatchError: [[an1,av1],[an1,av2],[an3,av3]] (of class java.util.LinkedList)*

and it looks like the combining has been performed correctly but then the return type is not the expected one in Scala.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to get the result I was looking for but probably not in the most efficient way.

Basically the are 2 step:

- Zip of the two list
- Explode of the list in rows

For the first step I defined the following UDF Function

```
UDF2 concatItems = new UDF2<Seq<String>, Seq<String>, Seq<String>>() {
    public Seq<String> call(final Seq<String> col1, final Seq<String> col2) throws Exception {
        ArrayList zipped = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0, listSize = col1.size(); i < listSize; i++) {
            String subRow = col1.apply(i) + ";" + col2.apply(i);
            zipped.add(subRow);
        }

        return scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(zipped);
    }

};
```

Missing the function registration to SparkSession:

```
sparkSession.udf().register("concatItems",concatItems,DataTypes.StringType);
```

and then I called it with the following code:

```
DataFrame df2 = df.select(col("ID"), callUDF("concatItems", col("AttributeName"), col("AttributeValue")).alias("AttName_AttValue"));
```

At this stage the df2 looks like that:

```
ID  AttName_AttValue
 0  [[an1,av1],[an1,av2],[an3,av3]]
 1  [[bn1,bv1],[bn2,bv2]]
```

Then I called the following lambda function for exploding the list into rows:

```
 DataFrame df3 = df2.select(col("ID"),explode(col("AttName_AttValue")).alias("AttName_AttValue_row"));
```

At this stage the df3 looks like that:

```
ID  AttName_AttValue
 0  [an1,av1]
 0  [an1,av2]
 0  [an3,av3]
 1  [bn1,bv1]
 1  [bn2,bv2]
```

Finally to split the attribute name and value into two different columns, I converted the DataFrame into a JavaRDD in order to use the map function:

```
JavaRDD df3RDD = df3.toJavaRDD().map(
            (Function<Row, Row>) myRow -> {
                String[] info = String.valueOf(myRow.get(1)).split(",");
                return RowFactory.create(myRow.get(0), info[0], info[1]);
        }).cache();
```

If anybody has a better solution feel free to comment.
I hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried and your example and got:
Undefined function: 'myNewFunc'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.