# Explode multiple columns in Spark SQL table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, explode

There was a question regarding this issue here:

[Explode (transpose?) multiple columns in Spark SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220916/explode-transpose-multiple-columns-in-spark-sql-table)

Suppose that we have extra columns as below:

```
**userId    someString      varA     varB      varC    varD**
   1        "example1"    [0,2,5]   [1,2,9]    [a,b,c] [red,green,yellow]
   2        "example2"    [1,20,5]  [9,null,6] [d,e,f] [white,black,cyan]
```

To conclude an output like below:

```
userId    someString      varA     varB   varC     varD
   1      "example1"       0         1     a       red
   1      "example1"       2         2     b       green
   1      "example1"       5         9     c       yellow
   2      "example2"       1         9     d       white
   2      "example2"       20       null   e       black
   2      "example2"       5         6     f       Cyan
```

The answer was by defining a `udf` as:

```
val zip = udf((xs: Seq[Long], ys: Seq[Long]) => xs.zip(ys))
```

and defining "withColumn".

```
df.withColumn("vars", explode(zip($"varA", $"varB"))).select(
   $"userId", $"someString",
   $"vars._1".alias("varA"), $"vars._2".alias("varB")).show
```

If we need to extend the above answer, with more columns, what is the easiest way to amend the above code. Any help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach with the `zip` udf seems ok, but you need to extend if for more collections. Unfortunately there is no really nice way to zip 4 Seqs, but this should work:

```
def assertSameSize(arrs:Seq[_]*) = {
 assert(arrs.map(_.size).distinct.size==1,"sizes differ") 
}

val zip4 = udf((xa:Seq[Long],xb:Seq[Long],xc:Seq[String],xd:Seq[String]) => {
    assertSameSize(xa,xb,xc,xd)
    xa.indices.map(i=> (xa(i),xb(i),xc(i),xd(i)))
  }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that the size of **varA,varB,varC,varD** remains same from your example.

```
scala> case class Input(user_id : Integer,someString : String, varA : Array[Integer],varB : Array[Integer],varC : Array[String], varD : Array[String])
defined class Input

scala> case class Result(user_id : Integer,someString : String , varA : Integer,varB : Integer,varC : String, varD : String)
defined class Result

scala> val obj1 = Input(1,"example1",Array(0,2,5),Array(1,2,9),Array("a","b","c"),Array("red","green","yellow"))
obj1: Input = Input(1,example1,[Ljava.lang.Integer;@77c43ec2,[Ljava.lang.Integer;@3a332d08,[Ljava.lang.String;@5c1222da,[Ljava.lang.String;@114e051a)

scala> val obj2 = Input(2,"example2",Array(1,20,5),Array(9,null,6),Array("d","e","f"),Array("white","black","cyan"))
obj2: Input = Input(2,example2,[Ljava.lang.Integer;@326db38,[Ljava.lang.Integer;@50914458,[Ljava.lang.String;@339b73ae,[Ljava.lang.String;@1567ee0a)

scala> val input_df = sc.parallelize(Seq(obj1,obj2)).toDS
input_df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Input] = [user_id: int, someString: string ... 4 more fields]

scala> input_df.show
+-------+----------+----------+------------+---------+--------------------+
|user_id|someString|      varA|        varB|     varC|                varD|
+-------+----------+----------+------------+---------+--------------------+
|      1|  example1| [0, 2, 5]|   [1, 2, 9]|[a, b, c]|[red, green, yellow]|
|      2|  example2|[1, 20, 5]|[9, null, 6]|[d, e, f]|[white, black, cyan]|
+-------+----------+----------+------------+---------+--------------------+

scala> def getResult(row : Input) : Iterable[Result] = {
     |             val user_id = row.user_id
     |             val someString = row.someString
     |             val varA = row.varA
     |             val varB = row.varB
     |             val varC = row.varC
     |             val varD = row.varD
     |             val seq = for( i <- 0 until varA.size) yield {Result(user_id,someString,varA(i),varB(i),varC(i),varD(i))}
     |             seq.toSeq
     |         }
getResult: (row: Input)Iterable[Result]

scala> val resdf = input_df.flatMap{row => getResult(row)}
resdf: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Result] = [user_id: int, someString: string ... 4 more fields]

scala> resdf.show
+-------+----------+----+----+----+------+
|user_id|someString|varA|varB|varC|  varD|
+-------+----------+----+----+----+------+
|      1|  example1|   0|   1|   a|   red|
|      1|  example1|   2|   2|   b| green|
|      1|  example1|   5|   9|   c|yellow|
|      2|  example2|   1|   9|   d| white|
|      2|  example2|  20|null|   e| black|
|      2|  example2|   5|   6|   f|  cyan|
+-------+----------+----+----+----+------+
```

If the size of columns varA,varB,varC or varD is different then those scenarios need to be handles.

You could iterate over the **max size** and output null values if values are not present in any columns by handling exceptions.

Comment: Thanks Ankush, What if the data was read from an external source such as hdfs. How can we fill-up the array created  in `case class Input(user_id : Integer,someString : String, varA : Array[Integer],varB : Array[Integer],varC : Array[String], varD : Array[String])`.

Comment: That becomes a separate question. What kind of data you load? What format it is in(csv/json)? You need to reformat the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend the UDF for more columns, do as below:

```
val zip = udf((xs: Seq[String], ys: Seq[String], zs: Seq[String]) =>
  for (((xs,ys),zs) <- xs zip ys zip zs) yield (xs,ys,zs))

df.withColumn("vars", explode(zip($"varA", $"varB", $"varC"))).select(
  $"userId", $"someString", $"vars._1".alias("varA"),
  $"vars._2".alias("varB"),$"vars._3".alias("varC")).show
```

This logic can be applied for n columns as required.