# Scala return multiple columns in an UDF after breaking a string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to break a string (technically strings passed from a column in a dataframe) and return these broken strings as list to dataframe.  Scala version 2.11.  I would prefer scala or pyspark solutions with udf's - because there is a lot happening inside the udf.

Let us say that I have a dataframe:

```
val df = List(("123", "a*b*c*d*e*f*x*y*z"), ("124", "g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o")).toDF("A", "B")
```

The result I want (in a udf, because there is a lot happening in there; Scala version 2.11) --

```
 A       B
123    ((a, b, c),
        (d, e, f),
        (x, y, z))
124    ((g, h, i),
        (j, k, l), 
        (m, n, o))
```

Write a udf to break this and return lists - but, I do not know how to define or pass schema to get the results back into the dataframe as three columns.

```
def testUdf =  udf( (s: String) => { 
  val a = s.split("\\*").take(3).toList
  val b = s.split("\\*").drop(3).take(3).toList
  val c = s.split("\\*").drop(6).take(3).toList
  val abc = (a, b, c).zipped.toList.asInstanceOf[List[String]]
  // println (abc) // This does not work
} )
val df2 = df.select($"A", testUdf($"B").as("B")) // does not work because of type mismatch.
```

I tried doing this - but, I do not know how to pass schema to the Udf above:

```
   val schema = StructType(List(
     StructField("C1", StringType),
     StructField("C2", StringType),
     StructField("C3", StringType)
   ))
```

Also, following this, I hope to follow the procedure outlined on [Explode multiple columns in Spark SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45386214/explode-multiple-columns-in-spark-sql-table?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)  to explode the dataframe.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The udf you defined is a from String to Unit - remove `abc` from the last line to return it
Also note that asInstanceOf[] doesn't change the type - you still have a tuple 
The below will give you a list of lists

```
def testUdf =  udf( (s: String) => { 
  val a = s.split("\\*").take(3).toList
  val b = s.split("\\*").drop(3).take(3).toList
  val c = s.split("\\*").drop(6).take(3).toList
  (a, b, c).zipped.toList.map(t=>List(t._1,t._2,t._3))
} )
```

Comment: I did add "abc" at the end as shown.  The statement for dataframe, df2, executes -- but df2.show -- causes some errors ---scala.MatchError: (a,d,x) (of class scala.Tuple3).  Without the last "abc", it causes java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Unit is not supported

Answer (score 2):

The way you generated arrays prior to `zipped` won't render the elements correctly.  One way to generate the elements in the wanted order is to use a 2-dimensional Array to pre-transpose the elements before applying `zipped`.

The following UDF will 1) split a string column into an array which gets transposed into a 2-D array, 2) zip the rows of the 2-D array into array of tuples, and 3) convert the array of tuples to a tuple of tuples (i.e. column type struct of structs):

```
val df = Seq(
  ("123", "a*b*c*d*e*f*x*y*z"),
  ("124", "g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o")
).toDF("A", "B")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def splitUdf = udf( (s: String) => {
  val arr = s.split("\\*")
  val arr2d = Array.ofDim[String](3, 3)

  for {
    r <- 0 until 3
    c <- 0 until 3
  } arr2d(r)(c) = arr(c * 3 + r)

  val arrTup = (arr2d(0), arr2d(1), arr2d(2)).zipped.toArray

  (arrTup(0), arrTup(1), arrTup(2))
} )

val df2 = df.select($"A", splitUdf($"B").as("B"))

df2.show(false)
// +---+-------------------------+
// |A  |B                        |
// +---+-------------------------+
// |123|[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[x,y,z]]|
// |124|[[g,h,i],[j,k,l],[m,n,o]]|
// +---+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem ist that your UDF returns `Unit` (last statement is return value). I would suggest the following procedure:

```
val df = List(("123", "a*b*c*d*e*f*x*y*z"), ("124", "g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o")).toDF("A", "B")

def testUdf = udf((s: String) => {
  val Array(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9) = s.split(s"\\*")
  Seq(
    (s1, s2, s3),
    (s4, s5, s6),
    (s7, s8, s9)
  )
})

val df2 = df.select($"A", explode(testUdf($"B")).as("B"))

df2.show()

+---+-------+
|  A|      B|
+---+-------+
|123|[a,b,c]|
|123|[d,e,f]|
|123|[x,y,z]|
|124|[g,h,i]|
|124|[j,k,l]|
|124|[m,n,o]|
+---+-------+
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer.  The major issue is that I cannot get to where I can use explode.  When I use the solution given by Arnon - I get Schema for type Any not supported.

Comment: @Shiva And what does not work if you use my solution?

Comment: From the original dataframe (given on the first line), I cannot get to the dataframe that you use.  When I use Arnon's answer, I get "Schema for type Unit is not supported" -- not in this problem, but, in the actual dataset that I am using.  I am getting List[List[Any]] and I cannot pass it out of the udf to the dataframe (before explode can work).