# Explode multiple columns of same type with different lengths

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, explode

I have a spark data frame with the following format that needs to be exploded. I check other solutions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45386214/explode-multiple-columns-in-spark-sql-table?rq=1). However, in my case, `before` and `after` can be arrays of different length.

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- before: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- start_time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- end_time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- area: string (nullable = true)
 |-- after: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- start_time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- end_time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- area: string (nullable = true)
```

For instance, if the data frame has just one row, `before` is a array of size 2 and `after` is an array of size 3, the exploded version should be have 5 rows with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- start_time: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- end_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- area: string (nullable = true)
```

where `type` is a **new column which can be `"before"` or "after"**.

I can do thss in two separate explodes where I make `type` column in each explode and `union` then.

```
val dfSummary1 = df.withColumn("before_exp", 
explode($"before")).withColumn("type", 
lit("before")).withColumn(
"start_time", $"before_exp.start_time").withColumn(
"end_time", $"before_exp.end_time").withColumn(
"area", $"before_exp.area").drop("before_exp", "before")

val dfSummary2 = df.withColumn("after_exp", 
explode($"after")).withColumn("type", 
lit("after")).withColumn(
"start_time", $"after_exp.start_time").withColumn(
"end_time", $"after_exp.end_time").withColumn(
"area", $"after_exp.area").drop("after_exp", "after")

val dfResult = dfSumamry1.unionAll(dfSummary2)
```

But, I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: doing them separately then union or join on id is what I do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also achieve this without union. With the data :

```
case class Area(start_time: String, end_time: String, area: String)

val df = Seq((
  "1", Seq(Area("01:00", "01:30", "10"), Area("02:00", "02:30", "20")),
  Seq(Area("07:00", "07:30", "70"), Area("08:00", "08:30", "80"), Area("09:00", "09:30", "90"))
)).toDF("id", "before", "after")
```

you can do

```
df
  .select($"id",
    explode(
      array(
        struct(lit("before").as("type"), $"before".as("data")),
        struct(lit("after").as("type"), $"after".as("data"))
      )
    ).as("step1")
  )
 .select($"id",$"step1.type", explode($"step1.data").as("step2"))
 .select($"id",$"type", $"step2.*")
 .show()

+---+------+----------+--------+----+
| id|  type|start_time|end_time|area|
+---+------+----------+--------+----+
|  1|before|     01:00|   01:30|  10|
|  1|before|     02:00|   02:30|  20|
|  1| after|     07:00|   07:30|  70|
|  1| after|     08:00|   08:30|  80|
|  1| after|     09:00|   09:30|  90|
+---+------+----------+--------+----+
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `exploding` the two columns separately followed by a `union` is a decent straightforward approach.  You could simplify the StructField-element selection a little and create a simple method for the repetitive `explode` process, like below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

case class Area(start_time: String, end_time: String, area: String)

val df = Seq((
  "1", Seq(Area("01:00", "01:30", "10"), Area("02:00", "02:30", "20")),
  Seq(Area("07:00", "07:30", "70"), Area("08:00", "08:30", "80"), Area("09:00", "09:30", "90"))
)).toDF("id", "before", "after")

def explodeCol(df: DataFrame, colName: String): DataFrame = {
  val expColName = colName + "_exp"
  df.
    withColumn("type", lit(colName)).
    withColumn(expColName, explode(col(colName))).
    select("id", "type", expColName + ".*")
}

val dfResult = explodeCol(df, "before") union explodeCol(df, "after")

dfResult.show
// +---+------+----------+--------+----+
// | id|  type|start_time|end_time|area|
// +---+------+----------+--------+----+
// |  1|before|     01:00|   01:30|  10|
// |  1|before|     02:00|   02:30|  20|
// |  1| after|     07:00|   07:30|  70|
// |  1| after|     08:00|   08:30|  80|
// |  1| after|     09:00|   09:30|  90|
// +---+------+----------+--------+----+
```