# Independently explode multiple columns in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a schema where each row contains multiple columns of arrays, and I want to explode each array column independently of each other one.

Suppose we have the columns:

```
**userId    someString      varA     varB       someBool
   1        "example1"    [0,2,5]   [1,2,9]        true
   2        "example2"    [1,20,5]  [9,null,6]     false
```

I want an output of:

```
userId    someString      varA     varB   someBool
   1      "example1"       0        null    true
   1      "example1"       2        null    true
   1      "example1"       5        null    true
   1      "example1"       1        null    true
   1      "example1"       20       null    true
   1      "example1"       5        null    true
   2      "example2"       null      1      false
   2      "example2"       null      2      false
   2      "example2"       null      9      false
   2      "example2"       null      9      false
   2      "example2"       null     null    false
   2      "example2"       null      6      false
```

Ideas?

(Oh, and I'm trying to this generically so I don't have to update the code as the schema changes, and also because the *actual* schema is kinda large...)

PS - Props to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45386214/explode-multiple-columns-in-spark-sql-table) very similar but different question from which I shamelessly stole the example data.

Edit: @oliik with a win, but, it would ALSO be awesome to see a way to this with `df.flatMap` (mostly because I still don't grok `flatMap`)

Comment: I am wondering if this can be done dynamically?

Comment: How do you get e.g. this row `2      "example2"       1        null    true`? In the source table `someBool==false <=> userId==2`

Comment: @ollik1 Typo :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always generate the select programmatically

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "example1", Seq(0,2,5), Seq(Some(1),Some(2),Some(9)), true),
  (2, "example2", Seq(1,20,5), Seq(Some(9),Option.empty[Int],Some(6)), false)
).toDF("userId", "someString", "varA", "varB", "someBool")

val arrayColumns = df.schema.fields.collect {
  case StructField(name, ArrayType(_, _), _, _) => name
}

val dfs = arrayColumns.map { expname =>
  val columns = df.schema.fields.map {
    case StructField(name, ArrayType(_, _), _, _) if expname == name => explode(df.col(name)) as name
    case StructField(name, ArrayType(_, _), _, _) => lit(null) as name
    case StructField(name, _, _, _) => df.col(name)
  }
  df.select(columns:_*)
}

dfs.reduce(_ union _).show()
```

```
+------+----------+----+----+--------+
|userId|someString|varA|varB|someBool|
+------+----------+----+----+--------+
|     1|  example1|   0|null|    true|
|     1|  example1|   2|null|    true|
|     1|  example1|   5|null|    true|
|     2|  example2|   1|null|   false|
|     2|  example2|  20|null|   false|
|     2|  example2|   5|null|   false|
|     1|  example1|null|   1|    true|
|     1|  example1|null|   2|    true|
|     1|  example1|null|   9|    true|
|     2|  example2|null|   9|   false|
|     2|  example2|null|null|   false|
|     2|  example2|null|   6|   false|
+------+----------+----+----+--------+
```

Comment: Okay, super cool. Can I get you to explain what's going on in the `select` that makes this work?

Comment: Ah, I guess, it's really, what's the magic of  `explode`, since I can get in there and check out the `columns` value.

Comment: Can you explain the case pls?

Comment: The idea is to "loop" through the array columns and apply the following to all columns: 1) explode column if it is the array column being looped 2)  replace the column with `null` values if the column is some other array column 3) keep it as it is if the column is not an array column. This gives 
`select("userId", "someString", explode("varA"), lit(null), "someBool")` and `select("userId", "someString", lit(null), explode("varB"), "someBool")`. 
Finally we union those data frames

Comment: I get that, but not this: ArrayType(_, _), _, _)   The _,_ on its own. I am going to try and I like a lot. Added one aspect that was missing for me. Well done.

Comment: It’s for catching all array types regardless of the parameters. ArrayType takes two parameters, element type and contains null. In this case we always want to match and thus ignore the values

Comment: Just saw it myself. Cool.

Comment: The clue is the array of dfs. I did not want to consider that initially. How is parallelism with "loop".

Comment: It’s not a concern here as all the operations used are lazy including union

Comment: Can't say I get that. Anyway.

Comment: @ollik1 Any ways to make this handle arrays nested inside structs? ...Would you maybe just wrap this in a function and recurse on `StructType`?

Comment: They could be exploded directly using syntax `explode($"a.b")`. However, if there are other fields under `a` they would be lost so yeah, maybe something recursive to catch them all

Comment: Hi there @Ollik1, in this particular case I think the 2nd match case `StructField(name, ArrayType(_, _), _, _) => lit(null) as name` will never be true since the pattern has already been applied to extract arrayColumns. Therefore it could be simplified to: `val dfs = arrayColumns.map { expname =>
      val columns = df3.schema.fields.map {
        case StructField(name, _, _, _) if expname == name => explode(df3.col(name)) as name
        case StructField(name, _, _, _) => df3.col(name)
      }
      df3.select(columns:_*)
    }`

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis That is needed as according to the question e.g. all values of `varB` should be `null` when exploding `varA`. If that `case` gets removed, the original values will be used instead

Comment: I see Ollik1 thanks, I am just saying that in this particular example this will never be true :) `case StructField(name, ArrayType(_, _), _, _) if expname != name` which implies that `case StructField(name, ArrayType(_, _), _, _) => lit(null) as name` will never be true as well

Comment: Interesting discussion and solution, for sure. One of may favourites, the 2nd LeoC has arrived!