# Duplicating current or lagging row

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have table1

```
number  type   time
--------------------
1       on     1
1       on     5
1       off    10
1       off    15
```

I need to transform it into table2

```
number  type   time    
--------------------
1       on     1
1       off    2
1       on     5
1       off    10
1       on     14
1       off    15
```

The conditions are if `$"type" === "ON" && $"lag_type" =!= "OFF"` I copy lagging row, but replace type with OFF and increment time by a second. If `$"type" =!= "ON" && $"lag_type" === "OFF"` I copy current row, but replace type with ON and decrease time by a second. If lag type is null skip.

I found which rows should be copied

```
val window = Window.partitionBy($"number").orderBy($"time")
df
.withColumn("lag_type", lag($"type", 1, null).over(window))
.withColumn("lag1", $"type" === "ON" && $"lag_type" =!= "OFF")
.withColumn("lag2", $"type" =!= "ON" && $"lag_type" === "OFF")
```

But don't know how to add rows. Especially if they are based on the values from the lagging one. For  the current one, I could probably make lists

```
type       time
(on, off)  (14, 15)
```

and explode them like it's show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220916/explode-transpose-multiple-columns-in-spark-sql-table), but again I'm lost when it comes to the lagging row.

Any advice? I'm using spark 2.2. Is it possible with case classes?

Comment: Please do upvote the answer as well if you found it useful :) @Eugene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to add rows ONLY FOR the cases where you find `lag1` or `lag2` is `true` .

One way of doing it :

```
//Filter only the rows that needs to be changed : 

val df2 = df.withColumn("lag_type", lag($"type", 1, null).over(window))
.withColumn("lag1", $"type" === "ON" && $"lag_type" =!= "OFF")
.withColumn("lag2", $"type" =!= "ON" && $"lag_type" === "OFF")
.filter( $"lag1"|| $"lag2")

 
//Change the rows based on the values of lag1 and lag2 
//then drop extra columns

val newChangedDf = df2
.withColumn("time",when($"lag1", $"time"+1).otherwise($"time"-1))
.withColumn("type",when($"lag1", lit("OFF")).otherwise(lit("ON")))
.drop("lag_type","lag1","lag2")

//Finally add them to the original df. 

val finalDf = df.union(newChangedDf)
```

Note : This doesn't handle the case when lag1 and lag2 both are `true` . Please manipulate the above code as per your requirement.